# issue with superset dashboard duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-restful, apache-superset

I am a beginner at Superset. While working I came across an issue i.e. when I am creating one dashboard. at a time same name dashboards are not created.  Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: I am able to create dashboards with same name. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am able to save 2 dashboards with same name in 1.3.2. Share the exact reproduction steps or any error you see.

Comment: What code do you expect me to share?